# Как центрировать элемент относительно другого

Tags: html, css

Имеется макет:
[image: макет]

Вопрос состоит в том, как центрировать **"Element 2"** относительно **"Element 1"**, чтобы **"Element 2"** занимал середину оставшегося пространства справа от **"Element 1"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предоставлю пример реализации с помощью `display:flex;`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.elements-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.element-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.container-element-1 {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /*определяет, сколько простанства flex-элемент будет занимать в контейнере flex*/
  /*поиграйтесь со значениям 0, 1, 2 и т.д., чтобы понять, как это работает*/
}

.container-element-2 {
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.element-1,
.element-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.element-1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.element-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements-wrapper">
  <div class="element-wrap container-element-1">
    <div class="element-1">Element 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element-wrap container-element-2">
    <div class="element-2">Element 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. В современных браузерах `display: flex;` поддерживается отлично. А вот в том же IE10 и ниже либо не очень, либо совсем нет.